# DriverManager.getConnection() doesn't work with OpenJDK

Tags: java, jdbc, executable-jar

I have an executable jar utility program that makes database queries.  It runs fine with Oracle Java.  However, if I run it with OpenJDK, it can't get the database connection.  The weird thing is there is no error or exception.  It just stops running the method.

I'm connecting to SQL Server.  I get "getDbConnection 2" output to the console, but nothing happens after that.  No errors, nothing.  I can't figure out why this works with standard Java but fails with OpenJDK.

Here is the code:

```
protected Connection getDbConnection()
{
    Connection conn = null;
    consoleWrite("getDbConnection 1");
    
    try {
        final String server = from_server.getText();
        final String port = from_port.getText();
        final String dbName = from_dbname.getText();
        String url = String.format("jdbc:sqlserver://%s:%s;databaseName=%s", server, port, dbName);
        String user = from_user.getText();
        final String pwd = from_pass.getText();
        consoleWrite("getDbConnection 2");
                    
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
        if (conn == null) {
            consoleWrite("conn not found");
        }
        consoleWrite("getDbConnection 3");
    }
    catch (SQLException se) {
        handleError(se);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ce) {
        handleError(ce);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        handleError(e);
    }
    
    return conn;
}
```

Comment: Which JDBC drivers do you have on the classpath when running the application? IIRC, some JDBC driver did (or still do) something wrong when they get loaded and register themselves, which causes a classloader deadlock. However, that behaviour happens in both Oracle Java as in OpenJDK (as the code used is identical). It also helps if you specify the exact Java version you use.

Comment: I'm using Java 1.8.0_321 and OpenJDK 11.0.2.  The driver I've added to the Class-Path is mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar.

Comment: Don't use OpenJDK 11.0.2, as "pure" OpenJDK release don't go beyond the first three months, IIRC. The latest Java 11 at this time is 11.0.15. Try using one of the OpenJDK builds from a vendor like Eclipse Adoptium to rule out a bug in your Java version.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I needed a newer JDBC driver.  After updating to mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar it works with OpenJDK 11.0.2 as well.